# DHCP Reservation vs Static IP address

Tags: networking, ip, dhcp, static-ip

So after browsing some websites, some people are telling me that static IP address is the best. But others say the DHCP Reservation is just as good if not the same.

So what is better? Or are they pretty much the same?

Well to help clarify some more. I reserved my PS3 and Wii U IP address in my router. Is that all right?

Comment: What websites have you been reading, and what points did they make?  It's a ridiculous argument really.  If you can assign via DHCP, do it.  If you can't, you're stuck assigning an manual address on the device.

Comment: One of the factors to take into account when evaluating articles written on this subject is that many learned to use static IPs because early consumer routers didn't have a mechanism for DHCP reservations.  Of the 3 answers available now @Wes Sayeed saysit the best... but I hate his first sentence.  I absolutely agree with the 3rd paragraph tho...

Answer (score 18):

Using DHCP reservations offers you a sort of poor-man's IP address management solution.  You can see and change IP addresses from a single console and makes it so you can see what addresses are available without having to resort to an Excel spreadsheet (or worse, a ping and pray system).

That being said, many applications require a static IP.  If the server is configured to use DHCP, the application has no way of knowing that a reservation exists and may refuse to install.  Also some applications tie their license to an IP address and therefore must be static as well.

Personally I prefer to use reservations when I can, and statics when I have to.  But when I do use a static, I make a reservation for that address anyway so that A) it can be within the scope with the rest of the servers, and B) still provides the visual accounting of the address.

NOTE: If you're referring to network devices like IP cameras and printers, reservations are definitely the way to go because you can add a comment in the reservation as to what the device is and where it's located.  Depending on the device, this may be your only means of documenting that information within the system.

Comment: Setting a reservation for a computer that has a static IP is also a good way of preventing IP address clashes.

Comment: I am very curious to know what software you run that requires a fixed IP address and is unable to know what that address is if that IP is assigned via DHCP.  I've also never seen any application permanently tying a license to a single IP address.

Comment: @Brad, you usually see this with line-of-business software that is used by specific industries.  A healthcare application used by some hospitals comes to mind.  To set it up on a terminal server I had to bind 25 static IP addresses to the NIC to have enough licenses to run it concurrently.  DHCP only allows you to reserve one IP address per MAC address.  On another occasion I had to set up an automated plasma cutter.  The device controller software didn't even have an option to use DHCP.  I have other examples too; those are just the first couple I've dealt with.

Comment: This is a great answer... the first line stinks tho, You start out by implying that it's the poor man's solution, but go on to sell the merits.

Comment: To call the the Poor-man's solution, you should explain what the more elegant rich-man's solution would be.  (Sorry for the double comment, the edit button for the one above is already gone.)

Comment: I'm not knocking it at all.  I just meant "poor-man's solution" as in it's built-in and therefore free.  There are IPAM solutions out there that cost money -- some lots of money -- and offer all kinds of features beyond your basic DHCP functions.

Comment: I agree with your comment, except for that part that many application require a static IP address. Most applications run fine without a static IP address, and even more of those work fine with a DHCP reservation. I would say **few** applications truly require a static IP address to operate properly.

Specialized equipment and system yes.

Answer (score 3):

As a printer tech, DHCP reservations are preferable to static IP assignments.  You can manage them centrally as well as ensure that the device always has the current DNS and other network info.

However, DHCP reservations require you to have access to the router/DHCP server, which as an outside vendor isn't always possible.  If you can't do DHCP reservations, use a static IP (being sure to manually enter subnet, DNS, etc.) but try to make it outside the DHCP scope if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I have never ran into a situation that I NEEDED to use a static but was more profitable to use one such as office laser jet printers (when you do always block the ip address from DHCP).

In my opinion laptops, phones, and any "mobile" devices should be reserved not static. It requires no set up on the device and the server will reserve that address for that device.

When it comes to printers and in certain cases workstations (if you need to know the address... for remote desktop ect.) always go static but remember to block the address from DHCP.

Remember though if you need to re-configure your subnet mask for any reason any and all static devices must be changed. Always think about future needs.

Answer (score 2):

I have several devices at home, that need fixed IP addresses and many others where I desire fixed IP addresses. Over the years I have discovered that the choice between static IP addresses or DHCP reservations depends on the nature of the application and convenience (how many and how often do you have to set them).

For devices whose configuration does not change often (NAS, desktops, VDI machines, print server, routers, switches) and where it takes little to no effort to change IP addresses, I prefer static addresses. For everything else (IP Cams, printers, thin clients, IoT devices), I use DHCP reservations. Setting a static IP on a computer is extremely easy; once set, I don't have to visit them for years. On the other hand, I may reset printers, IP cams, Raspberry Pi devices, UPS etc. several times. It is much easier to make DHCP reservations on the DHCP server for these devices, and expect to find the reset device at the same IP every time.

Regardless of how I set the IP, I always have a reservation on the DHCP server (for consistency sake) and I track them on a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

A manual IP allocation is always more worthy. As an administrator, it is very important to keep a track on users' activities and DHCP gives a new IP after every 8 days by default. In such cases you cannot maintain any record for your IP addresses. Also if you want to permit different internet access authority to different departments, manual IP allocation is the best and most reliable option.

Static techniques take time but its always better to go for a static IP address if you have a big network.

Comment: But DHCP reservation also ensure the same device will always get the same IP address.. so besides the above answers (where a static IP is a MUST and no option otherwise), you can still manage your devices IP address using DHCP reservation (and all done via a central console, without configuring every single client devices). Or am I missing something?

Comment: I agree with @Darius... and sorry Stephen, but your answer shows that you don't understand the concept of DHCP reservations.

Comment: Well thanks Tyson! yes I think I went on another track. Hope to serve better next time.