# How to configure DHCP server to automatically always provide client with same IP

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dhcp, ubuntu-14.04

I am working on creating a cluster configuration demo. I have three devices, one will be the head-node, two will be the compute-nodes. I am interested in using an unmanaged switch and have the two compute-nodes look to the head-node to get an IP address. Is it possible to configure my DHCP server (isc-dhcp-server) so that any device that connects always gets the same IP?

Answer (score 0):

In your dhcpd configuration file (typically `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`) you can set persistent IP leases for specific machines by MAC address with stanzas as

```
host foobar {
    hardware ethernet 08:01:02:03:04:05;
    fixed-address 192.168.17.34;
}
```

Of course, the IP addresses must be consistent with the remainder of your network configuration and `dhcpd.conf` as per the [`dhcpd.conf` manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcpd.conf).

Comment: Probably better known as a *fixed* or *reserved* IP address rather than *"persistent"*.  That adjective that you use does not appear with "address" or "lease" in the man page that you cite.    See also http://www.tech-faq.com/dhcp-reservation.html and https://superuser.com/questions/811156/dhcp-reservation-vs-static-ip-address